# How can I share a value between components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to reactjs and I am having a bad time trying to share a value I got from a blockchain network after I connect my wallet on my react website. The fact it is loading an other component after the connection, and I would like to have the value I got from the component of connection to the new component.

You can have a look here, the connection component in navbar.js where I need to send `wallet` to my second component in page2.js :

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container, Image, Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';

import { Link, scroller } from "react-scroll";

const Navigation = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const [ wallet, setWallet ] = useState("");
    const [ navBarShrink, setNavbarShrink ] = useState(false);

        const connect = async () => {
            const provider  = await web3Modal.connect();
            const web3      = getWeb3(provider);
            const accounts  = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
            const address   = accounts[0];
            const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
            const chainId   = await web3.eth.chainId();

            const newAccounts = await Promise.all(accounts.map(async (address: string) => {
            const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(address);

            const tokenBalances = await Promise.all(tokenAddresses.map(async (token) => {

            const tokenInst = new web3.eth.Contract(tokenABI, token.address);

            const balance = await tokenInst.methods.balanceOf(address).call();

            return {
              token: token.token,
              balance
            }
          }))

          return {
            address,
            balance: web3.utils.fromWei(balance, 'ether'),
            tokens: tokenBalances
          }
        }))
        
        setWallet(newAccounts);
    

    return (

        <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" className={ !navBarShrink ? ("navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-secondary text-uppercase fixed-top main_nav"): ("navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-secondary text-uppercase fixed-top main_nav navbar-shrink")} expand="lg" sticky="top">
            <Container>
                <Navbar.Brand>
                   Navbar code
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Container>
        </Navbar>
  );
}

export default Navigation;
```

And here is page2.js, where I need to show the values of the const 'wallet'

```
    import { Container, Image } from "react-bootstrap";
    
    
const Page2 = () => {
  return (
       <section className="page-section bg-primary text-blue mb-0">
           <Container>
                <div className="divider-custom divider-light">
                    <div className="divider-custom-line"></div>
                    <div className="divider-custom-line"></div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-lg-4 mr-auto"><p className="lead">wallet info is : {wallet}</p></div>
                </div>
            </Container>
                
        </section>
    
      );
    }
```

Thank you for your help, I hope you will understand me.
(I removed a lot of code to make it easier to understand)

Comment: you are not using any state management library like redux?

Comment: I don't think so, I am really new using reactjs

Comment: You could put it in Redux or use a Context. But much simpler, you can pass variables from one component to another as a prop. May I suggest reading the official docs — see https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: Thank you, I tried to use prop, but I think I have to use a format <div ... /> but I can't because I don't want to have the navbar code is the page2.js

Comment: read this blog: https://medium.com/coding-in-depth/reactjs-share-data-between-the-components-de492b129086

Comment: Maybe I didn't mean component but page also

Answer (score 0):

You can share the data between components in the following ways:

1. Using state management like Redux, Context API etc.,
2. If the components are related like parent and child you can send data as a prop
3. Using local storage **(this is not recommended)**